# How to populate ExpandableListView with data from database tables..?

Tags: android, sqlite, expandablelistview

I had googled a lot but didn't found any useful content about this topic. I want some thing like this:

```
+++++++++++
+ parent1 +
+++++++++++
      c1
-----------
      c2
+++++++++++
+ parent2 +
+++++++++++
      c3
-----------
      c4
-----------
```

parent & child must be coming from db....

Comment: look at https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge and http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/

Comment: Thanks for the reply Naveen...! But I want it using ExpandableListView...! :(

Answer (score 4):

I think [this tutorial](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/270612-how-to-get-started-with-expandablelistview/) helps you with Expandable ListView.

I used it before and it works!

**EDIT**:

To read from sqlite DB, check out [this link](http://android-er.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/simple-example-using-androids-sqlite.html). Once you have the data, use the first link to populate expandable list view.

There are plenty of tutorials on this bit. I just gave you one. You can find many more on the internet.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...! It is a great tutorial for a newbie like me...But i need to populate ExpandableListView from sqlite database.